# How to create Listview in fragment by data getting from server/internet

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

This is a fragment of Assignment Class that i want to load in onCreate() function of Assignments to show a list of items getting from server in Assignments activity but don't know how to pass list of data to this fragment as soon as i call setContentView() in Assignments or onCreateView() is called in this fragment.

```
package assignment;
public class assignment_list extends ListFragment  {
    ArrayList<String> assignments;
    String[] values;
    String selected_assignment_id;
     @Override   
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" };
                ((common_interface)getActivity()).intialize();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);


            setListAdapter(adapter);

            return super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);
        }



        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
          // do something with the data

            selected_assignment_id=values[position];
        }





    }
```

Comment: So you have gotten your data from the server at this point, corretct? If so I would recommend looking at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html and adding arguments to your fragments.

Comment: yes i did got, now i am giving try to your recomended link n will be back with feedback.:)

Comment: The idea behind setting arguments is that (because Fragments are reliant on an empty constructor) you can pass parameters to the fragment before the fragment view itself is actually created. It is kind of the get around to needing an empty constructor. You will pass your data as the argument and then populate your ListView in your fragment once it is created. Best of luck :)

Comment: zgc7009 it's good if we want to put something later but what to do when i want to show list fragment as the activity installs i.e in setContentView() b/c the fragment name is mentioned in xml to start first.

Comment: If that is the case what you should do is use findFragmentById() in your activity to get the fragment, and then create a method in your fragment called something like `attachData(YourDataType data)` and in that method build your list and all that good stuff. In other words, don't use the native fragment lifecycle methods to actually determine how your fragment is built. Sounds weird I know.

Comment: ok got it, but a little more help me please that when making a list in my custom function then how to return that view i.e listview

Comment: If you want the method to return the listView, make your method `public ListView attachData(YourDataType data)`, in attachData reference/build your ListView, and then return it when you are done building it. You shouldn't need to do that though, as your ListView should be managed by your Fragment if that is where it resides.

Comment: i mean how to attach my list with fragment/layout?

Comment: Sorry, forgot you were using a ListFragment. Just the array adapter stuff (including setListAdapter(adapter)) to the method I mentioned. The list fragmet itself acts as your list once the fragment's onCreateView method is called. As long as you call your method after onCreateView is called you should be fine.

Comment: zgc7009 we can't create a view custom function and that should be returned by onCreateView() auto as when i use a hard coded array in onCreateView() it works fine where in custom function neither hard coded val nor dynamic works.

Comment: If you want to make sure it is created in onCreateView, you need to hold off creating the activity/fragment in question until your server call is done. That is the only way I can think of making sure that it will work in onCreateView.

Comment: ahhh m trying and will let you know as soon as i got some solution. thankx 4 sharing your precious moments for me.